# Is it necessary to use this function to play sound?

Tags: swift, function, audio

I am new to programming and new to this website so a complete noob =)

I am doing a course online for swift and had two questions:

1. The first is about the first "playSound" - is it a function?? if yes why does it not have the function key?
2. Why are we creating a function for "soundName" - can we not just retrieve the data using "sender.currentTitle!" ?

I took a screenshot with comments to make it more clear.

The code:

```
@IBAction func keyPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    playSound(soundName: sender.currentTitle!)
}

func playSound(soundName: String) {
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: soundName, withExtension: "wav")
    player = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url!)
    player.play()
}
```

I really apologize if this is super stupid and not the right forum T_T

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4wmm.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `func playSound` is a function. `playSound(...)` in the first part *calls* that function.
2. Very good question! It's a matter of responsibilities. We want `func playSound` to be able to play *any* `.wav` file whose name it is given. It is a general file sound player. It happens that when *this* key is pressed, we want to play *this* file. But we could have *other* keys that play *other* files.

(But I would go even further: I'd argue that using the title of the button to tell us which file to play is bad code. You should never use the *interface* to function as the *data*.)